# Dismiss keyboard in a TextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I was just trying to hide the keyboard in a TextView using the following function in XCode 7.1.1 but it doesn't work.

How could I fix this?

```
class pictureViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var dedicatoriaCentradaTextView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        dedicatoriaCentradaTextView.delegate = self
    }

    func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

        if(text == "\n") {
            dedicatoriaCentradaTextView.resignFirstResponder()
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When overloading the `viewDidLoad()` method to set the delegate for your text view, possibly you should keep the super.viewDidLoad():

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Handle the user input in the text view through delegate callbacks
    dedicatoriaCentradaTextView.delegate = self
}
```

Thereafter, as you've almost tried correctly, use the `textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String)` method in the `UITextViewDelegate` protocol:

```
// UITextViewDelegate
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if text == "\n" {
        textView.resignFirstResponder()
        return false
    }
    else {
        return true
    }
}
```

But note that you use the local UITextView instance in the method above (local in method scope).

---

Using the suggestions above, your `pictureViewController` class should look like

```
class pictureViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var dedicatoriaCentradaTextView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Handle the user input in the text view through delegate callbacks
        dedicatoriaCentradaTextView.delegate = self
    }

    // UITextViewDelegate
    func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        if text == "\n" {
            textView.resignFirstResponder()
            return false
        }
        else {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Finally note that your class names should, by Swift coding convention, start with capital letters. I.e., rename your class `pictureViewController` to `PictureViewController`.

Comment: func textViewShouldEndEditing(dedicatoriaCentradaTextView: UITextView) -> Bool {
        dedicatoriaCentradaTextView.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

Smthg like this?

Comment: sure, updated, don't think I can be much clearer that this :) but lets remove all these "chatty" comments (as SO appeal to us to avoid extended discussions in comments)

Comment: I don't think I can make my answer any more specific, sorry. Using my answer above, I can achieve just what you are asking to do. Looks more like you need help with code review, try posting your code at http://codereview.stackexchange.com. Also, please delete some or all of your comments above, to follow SO "comment convention" (too chatty).

Answer (score 0):

Just call `endEditing` on your view.

Comment: If you are in a view controller: `[self.view endEditing:YES];`

Comment: func textViewShouldEndEditing(textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
        

        dedicatoriaCentradaTextView.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
  This doesn't work fine

Comment: @FactorJose: try my answer above.

Comment: @dfri it's for a TextView

Comment: @FactorJose I've updated my answer for a TextView instead of a TextField.

Comment: ??? The question is how to hide the keyboard, and this is clearly an answer to that.